# Convert TSQL to Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, t-sql, linq-to-entities

I have 2 table named FileList and ExtensionsCategory :

```
FileList
-------------------------------------------------------------
ID    Path         Extension

1     C:\7.pdf        pdf
2     D:\3.png        png
3     C:\1.mp3        mp3
4     D:\32.pdf       pdf
```

and

```
ExtensionsCategory 
------------------------------------------------------------
ID     Extension       Category

1        mp3           Multimedia
2        pdf           Document
3        png           Photo
```

there isn't any relation between tables.

now i want to know each category contain how many files ?
i wrote the following TSQL query in SSMS and work fine :

```
SELECT 
     Category
    ,SUM(FileCount) AS TotalFileCount 
FROM    
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(*) AS FileCount
        ,(SELECT ExtensionsCategories.Category FROM ExtensionsCategories WHERE FileList.Extension = ExtensionsCategories.Extension) AS Category
    FROM FileList GROUP BY Extension) AS T1 GROUP BY Category
```

i want know is there any improved way to do this without Joins ?

i try to write it using Linq to Entities, this is my code but i can't complete it :

```
    var a = _dbContext.FileLists
        .Select(fl => new
        {
            Extension = fl.Extension,
            Count = _dbContext.FileLists.Count(),
            Cat =
                _dbContext.ExtensionsCategories.Where(w => w.Extension == fl.Extension).Select(s => s.Category)
        }).GroupBy(g => g.Extension);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you correct result:-

```
var result = from f in _dbContext.FileLists
             group f by f.Extension into g
             let firstCategory = _dbContext.ExtensionsCategories
                                           .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Extension == g.Key)
             select new
                    {
                        Category = firstCategory != null ? firstCategory.Category : "",
                        TotalFileCount = g.Count()
                    };
```

Or if you need with `Method Syntax`:-

```
var result = _dbContext.FileLists.GroupBy(e => e.Extension)
              .Select(x =>
                  {
                      var firstCategory = _dbContext.ExtensionsCategories
                                           .FirstOrDefault(z => z.Extension == x.Key);
                      return new
                        {
                           Category = firstCategory != null ? firstCategory.Category : "",
                           TotalFileCount = x.Count()
                        };
                  });
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7T4azT) with Linq-to-objects.

**Update:**

If a category can contain multiple extension then you can use below query:-

```
var result = extensionCat.GroupBy(x => x.Category)
                      .Select(x =>
                         new
                          {
                              Category = x.Key,
                              TotalFileCount = fileList.Count(f => x
                                                    .Any(z => z.Extension == f.Extension))
                          }
                      );
```

Comment: @MojtabaTajik - Which data?

Comment: Sorry, i forget to ad link : https://dotnetfiddle.net/FJCIm9

Thinks we have more than one extension in same category .

Comment: @MojtabaTajik - Okay check my updated, it will work. Have updated the fiddle.

Comment: @MojtabaTajik - Hey I have updated the code again and this will be much simpler and should work with EF too.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to get the same results which might be faster.

First `GroupBy` file extension and `Count` them inside the `GroupBy` element selector. There you can also get the category name for the keys which are in this case file extensions:

```
var result =
    Files
    .GroupBy(x => x.Extension, (ext, fs) => new 
    { 
        Extension = ext, 
        Category = Categories.Single(c => c.Extension == ext).Name, 
        FileCount = fs.Count() 
    });
```

This will produce the following query:

```
SELECT [t1].[Extension], (
    SELECT [t2].[Name]
    FROM [Category] AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[Extension] = [t1].[Extension]
    ) AS [Category], [t1].[value] AS [FileCount]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], [t0].[Extension]
    FROM [File] AS [t0]
    GROUP BY [t0].[Extension]
    ) AS [t1]
```

[image: Groupped Files]

@RahulSingh version on the other hand produces this:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = ''
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT TOP (1) NULL AS [EMPTY]
            FROM [Category] AS [t2]
            WHERE [t2].[Extension] = [t1].[Extension]
            ) THEN (
            SELECT [t4].[Name]
            FROM (
                SELECT TOP (1) [t3].[Name]
                FROM [Category] AS [t3]
                WHERE [t3].[Extension] = [t1].[Extension]
                ) AS [t4]
            )
        ELSE CONVERT(NVarChar(50),@p0)
     END) AS [Category], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [File] AS [t5]
    WHERE (([t1].[Extension] IS NULL) AND ([t5].[Extension] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Extension] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t5].[Extension] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[Extension] = [t5].[Extension]))
    ) AS [TotalFileCount]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[Extension]
    FROM [File] AS [t0]
    GROUP BY [t0].[Extension]
    ) AS [t1]
```

---

I've tested both queries with 1.000.000 rows and the results are:

[image: Client Statistics - Fast]

vs. the `ToList` version:

[image: Client Statistic - Slow]

In the last rows of the statistics you can see that *short* version is about 3 times faster.