# Improve Linq query performance that use ToList()

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, linq-to-entities, query-performance

this code written by @Rahul Singh in this post [Convert TSQL to Linq to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255757/convert-tsql-to-linq-to-entities) :

```
var result = _dbContext.ExtensionsCategories.ToList().GroupBy(x => x.Category)
                .Select(x =>
                    {
                        var files = _dbContext.FileLists.Count(f => x.Select(z => z.Extension).Contains(f.Extension));
                        return new
                        {
                            Category = x.Key,
                            TotalFileCount = files
                        };
                    });
```

but this code have problem when used inside database context and we should use ToList() like this to fix "Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context" error :

```
var files = _dbContext.FileLists.Count(f => x.Select(z => z.Extension).ToList().Contains(f.Extension));
```

the problem of this is ToList() fetch all records and reduce performance, now i wrote my own code :

```
    var categoriesByExtensionFileCount =
        _dbContext.ExtensionsCategories.Select(
            ec =>
                new
                {
                    Category = ec.Category,
                    TotalSize = _dbContext.FileLists.Count(w => w.Extension == ec.Extension)
                });

    var categoriesTOtalFileCount =
        categoriesByExtensionFileCount.Select(
            se =>
                new
                {
                    se.Category,
                    TotalCount =
                        categoriesByExtensionFileCount.Where(w => w.Category == se.Category).Sum(su => su.TotalSize)
                }).GroupBy(x => x.Category).Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```

the performance of this code is better but it have much line of code, any idea about improve performance of first code or reduce line of second code :D

Regards, Mojtaba

Comment: If your code works and you simply want to "improve" it you should instead post on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Don't care about line count. It has nothing to do with performance.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter i want just know is it better way to do it

Comment: I don't like big LINQ queries too much and that's why, for me, the first step to improve your code is starting all over again :). In any case, it seems that the `.ToList().Contains(f.Extension)` bit can be replaced without any problem with `.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Extension == f.Extension) != null` (by assuming that the given type is nullable).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a navigation property from ExtensionCategories to FileLists.  If you are using DB First, and have your foreign key constraints set up in the database, it should do this automatically for you.

If you supply your table designs (or model classes), it would help a lot too.

Lastly, you can rewrite using `.ToList().Contains(...)` with `.Any()` which should solve your immediate issue.  Something like:

```
_dbContext.FileLists.Count(f => x.Any(z => z.Extension==f.Extension)));
```